# Number 277 805 is written 7 times in a row, and this way we get a 42-digit number

Tags: probability

Number 277 805 is written 7 times in a row, and this way we get a 42-digit number

```
   277 805 277 805 277 805 277 805 277 805 277 805 277 805.
```

Two random digits are crossed out of this number. What is the probability that a 40-digit number obtained is a multiple of 15?

Comment: Do you know how to tell directly from the digits of a number whether it's divisible by $15$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

By the divisibility criteria, the number must end in $0$ or $5$ and the sum of its digits must be a multiple of $3$.

Note that modulo $3$, the digits are $211202$ repeated $7$ times, i.e. $7\times0,14\times1,21\times2$, and you must cross-out either $1,1$ or $0,2$.

Answer (score 0):

I will call this new number (after crossed out digits) $N$. Then $15\mid N$ if and only if $5\mid N$ and $3\mid N$. Now the only way that $5\not\mid N$ is if the last 2 digits are both crossed out (so what is the probability of that). Furthermore, any $N\in \mathbb{N}$ is divisible by 3 if and only if the sum of its digits is divisible by 3 (of course working in base 10). You should be able to calculate the relevant probabilities from this

Comment: actually the divisibility by three sum of digits trick works in any base of form $3k+1$